# Jquery sliding gets more delayed for each click

Tags: jquery, delay, jquery-animate

If you login here
http://freeri.freehostia.com/utanme/image.php
Username/password:Demo123
and press any image and when it slides click the main image, do that a couple of times
and suddently you'll notice that the sliding takes longer and longer for each time.

the code im using

```
$(function(){
    $('.slide:last-child img').live('click', function() {
        $('.slide:first-child').animate({
            marginLeft: '0'
        },500);
        return false;
    });
    $('.slide .img').click(function(){
        var img = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        var title = $(this).find('h2').text();
        var desc = $(this).find('p').text();
        $('.slide:last-child img').attr('src',img);
        $('.slide:last-child h2').text(title);
        $('.slide:last-child #cont').text(desc);
        $('body').prepend('<div id="cover"><img src="./images/loader.gif"/></div>');
        $('.slide:last-child img').load(function(){
            $('#cover').detach();
            $('.slide:first-child').animate({
                marginLeft: '-900px'
            },500);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

what am i missing here?
any aid would be greatly appreciated

Comment: By the sliding takes longer and longer do you mean it takes longer for the slide animation to start or the duration is longer for the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.slide:first-child').stop(true,true).animate({ marginLeft: '-900px' },500});
```

About stop:
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Additionally I've had issues with live and load events on the same element (not saying it's what is causing your problem here.)

Might be not appropriate, but if you still have issues, try removing the live event before your subsequent load bind.
http://api.jquery.com/die/

Edit: Note it's probably bad for performance (to continuously remove and re-add the live binding).  I do not mean do this all the time but it may help pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Thanks, stop was useful for me. Subtle coding bug; when refreshing content I was asking an item to ensure it was closed (which kicked off the animation even when already hidden), this of course added up the close animation time for every time someone clicked refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling stop(true, true); when the animations allegedly end, there may be some strange calculations going on in the background that mess around with how the callback is set up. I have no idea if this will work, but it is worth a try. :)
-Thomas

Comment: i did 
                   $('.slide:first-child').animate({
    marginLeft: '-900px'
   },500,function(){
    stop(true, true);
   });

didnt help

Comment: $(this).stop(true, true); is what it is supposed to be... Did you write this script?